# How to resolve circular dependencies when using go modules and cgo

Tags: go, linker, cgo

In my project, I am using callbacks for bi-directional calls from C into go and vice versa using CGO. I resolved the issue of circular dependencies by compiling the C part into a library, then compiling the go part into a library, then a final linker pass puts it all together. This is working fine when not using go modules. Go source files are listed on the command line explicitly. I have been told that as of go 1.12 "this is not the right way to do it".

As the project has grown, I now want to use go modules. Unfortunately, this changes the behaviour of the go compiler. It now wants to resolve external dependencies and implicitly includes them in the output file. Due to the circular dependency, it now always ends up with an undefined reference or multiple definitions. How to resolve circular dependencies when using cgo and go modules "the right way"?

This is a minimal example to illustrate the problem. Remove the file-name "hello.go" from the call to go in the Makefile to see how it falls apart.

This is the error message:

```
hello.c:3: multiple definition of `c_hello'; $WORK/b001/_cgo_hello.o:/tmp/go-build/hello.c:3: first defined here
```

Makefile:

```
libchello.a: Makefile hello.c
    gcc -fPIC -c -o chello.o hello.c
    ar r libchello.a chello.o
libgohello.a: Makefile hello.go libchello.a
    env CGO_LDFLAGS=libchello.a go build -buildmode=c-archive -o libgohello.a hello.go
main: Makefile main.c libgohello.a libchello.a
    gcc -o main main.c libchello.a libgohello.a -pthread
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f main *.a *.o
    echo "extern void go_hello();" > libgohello.h
```

hello.go:

```
package main
/*
extern void c_hello();
*/
import "C"
import "time"
import "fmt"
//export go_hello
func go_hello() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello from go\n")
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    C.c_hello()
}
func main() {}
```

libgohello.h:

```
extern void go_hello();
```

hello.c:

```
#include "libgohello.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void c_hello() {
    printf("Hello from c\n");
    go_hello();
}
```

main.c:

```
void c_hello();
int main() {
    c_hello();
}
```

go.mod:

```
module hehoe.de/cgocircular
```

Comment: Do you really want an infinitely mutually recursive pair of functions calling between C and Go?

Comment: @JimB Point taken. Actually, this is a simplification for the sake of the example. The original [project](https://github.com/hoehermann/purple-gowhatsapp) uses requests from C into go and asynchronous callbacks from go into C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the verbose output from the `go build` command, you will see that when compiling the directory as a complete go package, the `main.c` file is being included as part of the C code used in `hello.go`.

From the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo):

> When the Go tool sees that one or more Go files use the special import "C", it will look for other non-Go files in the directory and compile them as part of the Go package

The easiest solution here is to separate the main C and Go packages, so that they don't interfere with each other's build process. Testing this out, removing the `main.c` file will build `libchello.a` and `libgohello.a`, and then adding it back in will complete the build of `main`.

Comment: Another fine example of "How RTFM can save your day". :) It works for the example. Modules are working. However, it seems like `go build` does not recurse into sub-directories as soon as cgo is involved. So I cannot have anything but a main package.

Comment: @Hermann, Using `cgo` doesn't effect how `go build` works with overall packages, it never recurses into directories to build (even the std library uses cgo, and you don't go into each package to build them independently). The go tool however will build all required dependencies automatically, which may happen to be located in subdirectories, but their location is only determined by the import and module paths.

Comment: I was not aware I had to use the "absolute" path in the import. Thank you.